# Collectd ping plugin showing ping_host_add failed

Tags: collectd

After installing the collectd ping plugin and starting collectd , the following is shown in the /var/log/messages

```
Sep 29 22:35:36 localhost collectd[77162]: ping plugin: ping_host_add (1.2.3.5) failed: Operation not permitted
Sep 29 22:35:36 localhost collectd[77162]: ping plugin: No host could be added to ping object. Giving up.
Sep 29 22:35:46 localhost collectd[77162]: ping plugin: The ping thread had a problem. Restarting it.
Sep 29 22:35:46 localhost collectd[77162]: read-function of plugin `ping' failed. Will suspend it for 20.000 seconds.
Sep 29 22:35:46 localhost collectd[77162]: ping plugin: ping_host_add (1.2.3.5) failed: Operation not permitted
Sep 29 22:35:46 localhost collectd[77162]: ping plugin: No host could be added to ping object. Giving up.
Sep 29 22:36:06 localhost collectd[77162]: ping plugin: The ping thread had a problem. Restarting it.
Sep 29 22:36:06 localhost collectd[77162]: read-function of plugin `ping' failed. Will suspend it for 40.000 seconds.
```

Following is the ping plugin configuration in collectd.conf

```
LoadPlugin ping
<Plugin ping>
   Host "1.2.3.5"
   Interval 1.0
   Timeout 0.9
   TTL 255
   SourceAddress "1.2.3.4"
   Device "eth0"
   MaxMissed -1
</Plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem with permission denied message from the collectd ping plugin. SELinux was blocking access from the ping plugin, even when I was running collectd as root. To work around this I set SELinux to permissive:

```
setenforce Permissive
```

There's probably a more surgical way to setup SELinux to not have to set it to permissive.